# How to design gray from left side of page and right side of page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I work on asp.net MVC layout page . I need to make page layout layout from left side of page and right side of page are gray .

but I don't know how to do that using html and CSS or bootstrap .

exactly what I need is to how to assign left side and right side with gray as image

sample I need to make it as below :

layout page as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Resignation Submission Form</title>
   





    <style>
        .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin-top:-50px;
            margin-left: 130px;
            padding-left: 130px;
        }

        .header {
            width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns:34mm 102mm 34mm;*/
            display: flex;
        }

      

        .header-Title {
            flex: 1;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .header-CompanyLogo {
            width: 150mm;
            display: flex;

        }
        
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            
            <div class="header-Title">
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:30px;">Employee Self Service</b>
                <br /><br />
                <b style="font-size:12px;"><u></u></b>

            </div>
            @*<div class="header-CompanyLogo">
            <img src="~/Images/CompanyLogo.jpg" style="max-height: 23mm; margin: 1px;" />
        </div>*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
  
    <div class="container body-content">
        
        <footer>
            <p>Resignation Submission Form Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

  


   

</body>
</html>
```

[image: sample gray from left and right]

Updated post

only need to modify script above to accept gray on left and right only exclude middle
so can you help me ?

can you show me on fiddle or sample please ?

Comment: You have at least one typo in your CSS.

Comment: so how to do it please

Comment: First, fix your typo (and any other errors). Then see if that fixes your issue. If it doesn't, come back here and update your question to match.

Comment: i updated my post can you show me how to assign gray on left and right of page layout as image above please

Comment: Set the background of the `body` to gray and the background of the `.container` elements to white?

Comment: can you show me please by sample fiddle as you like if you need modify my code or from sample you have it any one can accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the CSS part of the code, so you can see now that the left and right sides of the page are gray, while the middle content area is white:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Resignation Submission Form</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #b5b7bb; /* Set the background color for the entire page */
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 80%; /* Set a max-width for the content area */
            margin: 0 auto; /* Center the content area horizontally */
            background-color: #fff; /* Set the background color of the container to gray */
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Add a subtle shadow to the content area */
        }

        .header {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .header-Title {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .body-content {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        footer {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-Title">
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                <br />
                <b style="font-size:30px;">Employee Self Service</b>
                <br /><br />
                <b style="font-size:12px;"><u></u></b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="container body-content">
            <!-- Your content goes here -->
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Resignation Submission Form Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```